# How to reserve a place for an empty single character

Tags: java, android, whitespace

I want to reserve the space for an empty single character in the beginning of a `TextView` in my android app, 
I tried by adding a **single whitespace** in the beginning of my `TextView` text like:

```
mTextView.setText(" 00");
```

but **" 00"** NOT equal **"000"** in the Layout space occupied, I tried two begin with **two** spaces but it also was smaller, and **three** spaces but this time it was larger, I tried even to create another prior `TextView` with the value of a single space char `m2TextView.setText(' ');` but also didn't fit.

Comment: With all the great functionality android provides for layout, why do you need to rely on whitespaces?

Comment: @popovitsj it's something related to give the user the full control in some issue, and despite I can find another way, that question mainly came out of my curiosity, may be I can learn something that I don't know

Comment: I would say you need to switch to a monospace Font, but switching fonts is one of these things that are a real pain in Android.

Answer (score 1):

What about using SpannableString?

For instance you could do it like this:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&nbsp;00"));
```

Or you can use a blank drawable (here R.drawable.empty) in the Spannable string:

```
Spannable spannableText = new SpannableString(" 00");
spannableText.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.empty, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    myTextView.setText(spannableText);
```

Comment: got tip, but still gives the same result

Comment: added other spannable possibility above in the solution